# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript

I am creating a button, who has a click event, which need an id to work.

This line is creating the error:

```
button.addEventListener("click", e => LikeComment(result[i].id));
```

Now, when debugging I can tell that is knows that result[i].id is 1. So obviously it is capable of getting it.

Update:

This is the javascript method

```
function GetComments(id) {
   
   
   
        comment.style.display = 'block';
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/GetComments',     
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    
                    var buttonId = "LikeComment" + result[i].id;
                    
                }


            },
        });
    


}
```

This is where I get the array from

```
 public JsonResult GetComments(long postId)
        {
            var comment1 = new Comment()
            {
                Id = 1,
            };
            var comment2 = new Comment()
            {
                Id = 2,      
            };

            Comment[] comments = { comment1, comment2 };
            return Json(comments);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise, we cannot help.

Comment: What value is `i` set to? Is `i` outside the bounds of the array size?

Comment: Sorry. What a sec and I will update the post with more information.

Comment: My assumption is the error is correct and your result array in your listener is empty, based on your getComments method you never assign the result to some accessible scope result variable.

Comment: @Estradiaz What do you mean "accessible scope result variable"?

Comment: the result in your ajax success callback is only accessible within this callback, and as your code does not assign the result reference in the callback ... or is there code missing?

Comment: @Estradiaz I'm not sure what you mean, when you say 'within this callback'.